# How can I edit a datetime in a <td><input> value using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, html-table

I want to automatically update the datetime in a `<td>` tag but I can't quite figure out how to get the jQuery to work in tables.

I will then want to reset to the default datetime value if the checkbox gets unchecked, but I'll try and figure that part out on my own.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#finishedCheckbox').click(function() {
    var time = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss');
    $('#dateTimeFinished').val(time);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- Add datetime to datetimefinished when clicked -->
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="finishedCheckbox" id="finishedCheckbox" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="datetime-local" value="" name="dateTimeFinished" id="dateTimeFinished"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you repeating the same `#finishedCheckbox` id on multiple elements in the table, eg. one per row? If so, that's the problem.

Comment: i was legit missing the moment library in my file... wow -_-, thank you for updating the code i posted.

Comment: No problems, at least you you got the answer you needed, even if it wasn't the one you expected :)

Comment: yes, that seems to be how learning to code goes. I appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Instead, you should use:

```
var time= new Date;
```

Comment: Not my downvote... but...  OPs issue is with repeating the same `id=` on each row then using `$("#id")` - which will only select the first match.  The format of the date / value being set in the corresponding input is irrelevant.

Comment: idk who downvoted but I got it working thanks to the person who edited my post, the issue was I was missing a link to the moment.js library I needed. the id wasn't the issue. Easy fix, something I would have probably never even noticed, coding is like that sometimes :)